# Converting JSONObject String into php array of name value pairs

Tags: php

I have a json string i am sending to my php server as

```
{"1":"abced","6":"abcdef"}
```

Where 1 and 6 are different userIds for database entries and abcdef their respective values.

How can convert this string into different name value pairs?

Here is what i have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_decode($my_json_string, true)` will do the trick for you. 
For more details, see here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: mate i have already tried this. after $ringCatsArray = json_decode($ringCats, true);
        return $ringCatsArray; the above string is the result of ringCatsArray. My question is what should i do next

Comment: I must admit i am surprised. The output you show in your question looks like valid json. So it should not be the result of `json_decode()`. Could it be that your error is elsewhere? Have you tried a `var_dump` immediately after json_decode?

Comment: i thought so, it seems the json representation in my iphone code is weird containing characters that might not be recognized by json_decode. However i have come up with array_keys() to get keys and then foreach($ringCatsArray as $ringCat) to get values. since i can't editclient side code.